# Overlapping of dropdown menu in mobile view when fixed-top is used

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In mobile view as i click on hamburger button the dropdown menu gets overlapped with the content.Even while scrolling down the content is being overlapped.

```html
        <div class="background my-0 mx-0 fixed-top">
          <nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
            
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TAVISH DESIGN STUDIO</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto justify-content-end">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" href="#">HOMEPAGE</a>
                </li>`enter code here`
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">OUR CLIENTS</a>
                </li>`enter code here`
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">CAREERS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hello.. You need to add few more details about the exact issue you are facing, thereby it will be easier for others to test your issue and you will also get a solution much faster. 
There are different css classes used in the html you provided, unless you are sharing those css and a screenshot of the issue, it will be difficult for others to help you properly..

Comment: I'll surely look forward to it.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Add background solid color to navbar list like below:

```
.navbar-collapse.show {
 background: white;
}
```